# Sum or difference of two powers of two

Tags: code-golf, math

Your challenge, should you choose to accept it, is, given an integer `K >= 1`, find non-negative integers `A` and `B`  such that at least one of the two conditions following hold:

1. `K = 2^A + 2^B`
2. `K = 2^A - 2^B`

If there does not exist such `A` and `B`, your program may behave in any fashion. (To clarify, `A` and `B` can be equal.)

### Test cases

There are often multiple solutions to a number, but here are a few:

```
K => A, B
1 => 1, 0
15 => 4, 0                      ; 16 - 1 = 15
16 => 5, 4                      ; 32 - 16 = 16; also 3, 3: 8 + 8 = 16
40 => 5, 3                      ; 2^5 + 2^3 = 40
264 => 8, 3
17179867136 => 34, 11           ; 17179869184 - 2048 = 17179867136
```

The last test case, `17179867136`, **must run in under 10 seconds** on any relatively modern machine. This is a code golf, so the shortest program in bytes wins. You may use a full program or a function.

Comment: Can **A** equal **B**?

Comment: @Dennis I don't see why not.

Comment: ... and for `16`, both `5,4` and `3,3` are valid.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, can `A`, `B` be negative? (e.g. `-1, -1` for 1)

Comment: @Sp3000 No, good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
;0+N&$BL€’
```

Applying the bit twiddling trick from [the Python answer by @xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92864/53748)

Test it at [**TryItOnline**](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=OzArTiYkQkzigqzigJk&input=&args=MTU)
All test cases are also at [**TryItOnline**](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=OzArTiYkQkzigqzigJkKxbzDh-KCrOG5hOKCrOG4ozA&input=&args=MTUsMTYsNDAsMjY0LDE3MTc5ODY3MTM2)

How?

```
;0+N&$BL€’ - main link takes an argument, k, e.g 15
;0         - concatenate k with 0, e.g. [15, 0]
     $     - last two links as a monad
   N       - negate, e.g. -15
    &      - bitwise and, e.g. -15&15=1 since these two are called as a monad (one input)
  +        - add, vectorises, e.g. [16,1]
      B    - convert to binary, vectorises, e.g. [[1,0,0,0,0],[1]]
       L€  - length for each, e.g. [5,1]
         ’ - decrement, vectorises, e.g. [4,0]
```

Answer (score 15):

### Python 2, 43 bytes

```python
lambda n:[len(bin((n&-n)+k))-3for k in n,0]
```

Say that `n==2^a ± 2^b` with `a>b`. Then, the greatest power-of-2 factor of `n` is `2^b`, and we can find it using the bit-trick `2^b = n&-n`. That lets us compute `2^b + n`, which equals either `2^a + 2 * 2^b` or just `2^a`. Either one has the same-length bit-length as `a`*. So, we output the bit-lengths of `n&-n` and `(n&-n)+n`, computed from the lengths of their binary representations. Python 3 is one byte longer for parens in `for k in(n,0)]`.

*Except that `2^a + 2^b` with `a==b+1` has one longer bit-length, but that's fine because we can interpret that as `2^(a+1)-2^b`.

Comment: Wonderful - I looked for a bit fiddle, but couldn't work it out, just ported to Jelly.

Comment: Try `n=4` or `8` or `16` please.

Comment: @Titus `f(2**n)` returns `(n+1,n)` and `2**(n+1)-2**n=2**n` so there is no problem.

Comment: ah ... What´s the format of `bin()` in Python?

Comment: @Titus it's a string with a leading `0b`, hence the `-3`.

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (ES6), 73 bytes

```
(n,[s,f,z]=/^1+(.*1)?(0*)$/.exec(n.toString(2)))=>[s.length-!!f,z.length]
```

For the subtraction case, the first number is the number of digits in the binary representation and the second number is the number of trailing zeroes. For the addition case, we subtract 1 from the first number. If the binary representation is all 1s followed by some 0s then the addition case is assumed otherwise the subtraction case is assumed. 36-byte port of @xnor's version that only works for B≤30 in JavaScript:

```
n=>[(l=Math.log2)(n+(n&=-n))|0,l(n)]
```

Comment: @ETHproductions Sure, but I golfed it down to 36.

Comment: My bad, I thought that the 36-byte version didn't work for the 17 billion test case.

Comment: @ETHproductions It doesn't, but then neither did your port, as I recall (comment since deleted, sigh), since it used bitwise operations.

Comment: Sorry, here it is again: `n=>[n,0].map(k=>((n&-n)+k).toString(2).length-1)` And both versions return `[34,11]` on the last test case (I'm using FF 48).

Comment: @ETHproductions Aha, so more accurately they work when the second result is 30 or less.

Answer (score 6):

## Perl, <s>52</s> <s>49</s> 32 bytes

Old solution (49 bytes)

Includes +1 for `-p`

Give input on STDIN:

```
pow2.pl <<< 17179867136
```

`pow2.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$_=reverse sprintf"%b",$_;/()1(?:1+|0*)/;$_="@+"
```

However, using xnor's algorithm and adding a twist gives 32 bytes:

```
perl -nE 'say 13/9*log|0for$;=$_&-$_,$_+$'
```

Just the code:

```
say 13/9*log|0for$;=$_&-$_,$_+$
```

This suffers from severe rounding error because `13/9 = 1.444...` is quite a bit above `1/log 2 = 1.44269...` (`log` itself also has a rounding error but that is so much smaller that we can wrap it up in the analysis of 13/9). But since any `2**big - 2** small` gets corrected to `2** big` before the log this doesn't mater and the calculation for `2**big + 2 * 2**small` gets truncated  down so is also safe..
And at the other side of the range `2**n+2**(n-1)` doesn't get increased enough in the range `[0,64]` (I can't properly support more than the integer range anyways due to the use of `&`) to lead to a wrong result (multiplicator `1.5` however would be too far off for large numbers).

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 23 bytes

```
,A:B#+.:2rz:^a{+|-}?,.=
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=LEE6QiMrLjoycno6XmF7K3wtfT8sLj0&input=MTcxNzk4NjcxMzY&args=Wg)

This is much faster than required, e.g. [this is still under 10 seconds on TIO](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=LEE6QiMrLjoycno6XmF7K3wtfT8sLj0&input=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&args=Wg&debug=on).

#### Explanation

This is basically a direct transcription of the formula with no optimization:

```
,A:B     The list [A, B]
#+       Both A and B are greater than or equal to 0
.        Output = [A, B]
:2rz     The list [[2, A], [2, B]]
:^a      The list [2^A, 2^B]
{+|-}?   2^A + 2^B = Input OR 2^A - 2^B = Input
,.=      Assign a value to A and B which satisfy those constraints
```

Comment: It looks like this challenge was made for the language :D

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>57</s> 54 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to LegionMammal978!*

```
Do[Abs[2^a-#]==2^b&&Print@{a,b},{a,2Log@#+1},{b,0,a}]&
```

Actually prints out all<sup>1</sup> appropriate pairs {a,b}. `2Log@#+1` is an upper bound for the largest `a` that can possibly appear when representing the input `#` (the tight upper bound is Log[2#]/Log[2] = 1.44... Log[#] + 1). Runs almost instantaneously on the test input, and in less than a quarter second (on my new but off-the-shelf computer) on 100-digit inputs.

<sup>1</sup> Letting `a` start at the default value of 1 instead of 0 saves two bytes; it causes the output {0,0} to be missed when the input is 2, but finds the output {2,1} in that case, which is good enough.

Comment: **All*** appropriate pairs? (Also, `If[Abs[2^a-#]==2^b,Print@{a,b}]` can be replaced with `Abs[2^a-#]==2^b&&Print@{a,b}` to save 3 bytes.)

Comment: Nice observation, I get it! "All*" was a footnote, but it's clearer now.

Answer (score 4):

## Python, 69 bytes

```python
def f(k):b=bin(k)[::-1];return len(b)-2-(b.count('1')==2),b.find('1')
```

Tests are on [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/LZAsgu)

Since non-valid input can do anything, we know that if the input has exactly 2 bits set it is the sum of those 2 powers of 2, and otherwise (if valid) it will be be a run of some number of bits (including the possibility of just 1 bit) and will be the difference between the next highest power of 2 than the MSB and the LSB set.

Answer (score 4):

### JAVA 7 ,<del>142</del> ,<del>140</del>, 134 BYTES

This is my first post on PPCG!I would really appreciate for feedback on golfing tips
  
*Thanks to **frozen** for saving 2 bytes*

```
void f(long n){for(int i=-1,j;i++<31;)for(j=0;j++<34;){long a=1,x=a<<i,y=a<<j;if(x+y==n|y-x==n){System.out.println(j+" "+i);return;}}}
```

### UNGOLF

```
void f(long n){
    for(int i=-1,j;i++<31;)
         for(j=0;j++<34;){
          long a=1,x=a<<i,y=a<<j;
            if(x+y==n|y-x==n){
            System.out.println(j+" "+i);
        return;
        }
            }
    }
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/1kge2K)

Comment: Hi numberknot! Another wanderer from puzzling I see. It does not seem to work for `40=2**3+2**5`, for example. Looking at it, I can't see why not, maybe I [made a transcription error](http://ideone.com/k1tUoV)...

Comment: @JonathanAllan Now it works fine.Actually the brackets were missing in this line if((a<<i)+(a<<j)==n|(a<<j)-(a<<i)==n) and thanks.

Comment: Can´t you use a literal `1` instead of declaring a variable for it?

Comment: @TItus if I use literal 1 then this testcase(17179867136 ) would not be possible because if you use literal 1 then java automatically assigned it an INT memory space.

Comment: You can declare j together with i: `for(int i=-1,j;[...]`

Comment: +1 You can golf it some more, though. `a=1,` can be removed and both `a`s can be replaced with `1L`. You can return a String instead of printing directly. And you can remove the second `long` and add `,x,y` in the for-loop, and assign them directly in the if-check so you can remove the for-loop brackets. So total becomes this: (**119 bytes**) `String f(long n){for(long i=-1,j,x,y;i++<31;)for(j=0;j++<34;)if((x=1L<<i)+(y=1L<<j)==n|y-x==n)return j+" "+i;return"";}`

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```
BnQ:qWtG-|ym)1)tG-|hZl
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Qm5ROnFXdEctfHltKTEpdEctfGhabA&input=MTcxNzk4NjcxMzY) Or [verify all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=IkAKQm5ROnFXdEAtfHltKTEpdEAtfGhabA&input=WzE1IDE2IDQwIDI2NCAxNzE3OTg2NzEzNl0).

#### Explanation

```
B      % Implicit input. Convert to binary. Gives n digits
nQ:q   % Range [1 ... n+1]
W      % 2 raised to that, element-wise: gives [1 2 4 ... 2^(n+1)] (*)
tG-|   % Duplicate. Absolute difference with input, element-wise (**)
y      % Push a copy of (*)
m      % True for elements of (**) that are members of (*)
)      % Use as logical index to select elements from (*)
1)     % Take the first element. Gives power of the first result
tG-|   % Duplicate. Absolute difference with input. Gives power of the second result
hZl    % Concatenate. Take binary logarithm. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 41 bytes

```perl6
{.base(2).flip~~/1[1+|0*]/;$/.to,$/.from}
```

( Algorithm shamelessly copied from [the Perl 5 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92850/a/92858#92858) )

### Explanation:

```perl6
# bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣
{
  # turn into binary
  # ( implicit method call on ｢$_｣ )
  .base(2)

  # flip the binary representation
  .flip

  ~~ # smartmatch that against:

  /
    1      # a ｢1｣
    [
      | 1+ # at least one ｢1｣
      | 0* # or any number of ｢0｣
    ]
  /;

  # returns a list comprised of

  # the position of the end of the match (larger of the two)
  $/.to,
  # the position of the beginning of the match
  $/.from
}
```

### Usage:

```perl6
# give it a lexical name for clarity
my &bin-sum-diff = {.base(2).flip~~/1[1+|0*]/;$/.to,$/.from}

say bin-sum-diff 15; # (4 0)
say bin-sum-diff 16; # (5 4)

say bin-sum-diff 20; # (4 2)
# 2**4==16, 2**2==4; 16+4 == 20

say bin-sum-diff 40; # (5 3)
say bin-sum-diff 264; # (8 3)
say bin-sum-diff 17179867136; # (34 11)
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 73 bytes

I could have copied Jonathan´s Pyhton 2 solution for 54 bytes (+13 overhead),
but wanted to come up with something different.

save to file, then execute with `php` or `php-cgi`.

```
<?=strlen($n=decbin($argv[1]))-!!strpos($n,'01')._.strpos(strrev($n),49);
```

prints `a` and `b` separated by an underscore, anything for no solution.

**distinctive solution, 96 bytes**

```
<?=preg_match('#^(10*1|(1+))(0*)$#',decbin($argv[1]),$m)?strlen($m[0])-!$m[2]._.strlen($m[3]):_;
```

prints `a` and `b` separated by an underscore; a sole underscore for no solution.

It even tells you the operation for 11 more bytes:
Just replace the first underscore in the code with `'-+'[!$m[2]]`.

Comment: If I try 67 in echo strlen($n=decbin($argv[1]))-!!strpos($n,'01').'-+'[!$n[2]].strpos(strrev($n),49); it gives me back 6+0 which is 65

Comment: @JörgHülsermann: 67 has no solution; behaviour for no solution is undefined; so it does not matter what it prints for 67.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP ,117 Bytes

```
if(preg_match("#^(1+|(10*1))0*$#",$b=decbin($k=$argv[1]),$t))echo($l=strlen($b))-($t[2]?1:0).",",$l+~strrpos($b,"1");
```

Extended version 4 Cases

```
$l=strlen($b=decbin($k=$argv[1]));
// Case 1: n=2(n-1)=n+n or n=n*(2-1)=2n-n 
if(preg_match('#^100*$#',$b))echo($l-2).'a+'.($l-2).':'.$l.'a-'.($l-1);
// Case 2: n-m
elseif(preg_match('#^1+0*$#',$b)){echo $l.'b-',strpos($b,"0")?$l-strpos($b,"0"):0;}
// Case 3: n+m 
elseif(preg_match('#^10*10*$#',$b))echo ($l-1).'c+',$l-strrpos($b,"1")-1;
else echo "Nothing";
```

the short version union Case 1 and 3 and makes a Difference to Case 3 and in both versions Case 4 gives no output.